# PPPoE connection type with VoIP service

Tags: networking, dhcp, voip, sip, pppoe

Two VoIP ATA adapters is used for VoIP service, adapters are in different offices, but within same VoIP service networks. The PPPoE connection type is used in ATA for VoIP service: is it possible to setup (duplicate) one SIP account on two separate VoIP ATA devices? Surely, only one at a time VoIP adapter will be used for Voip calls. The PPPoE connection type itself should not impose restrictions on such configuration of VoIP account within network? As far as I know such configuration worked when ATA adapters was configured with DHCP connection type.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible to setup (duplicate) one SIP account on two separate VoIP ATA devices?

This should not be possible, assuming the VoIP provider knows what they are doing.

> As far as I know such configuration worked when ATA adapters was configured with DHCP connection type.

A SIP device has to register with a SIP server. The SIP server should reject duplicate registrations if it is correctly configured. The registration will include the SIP Telephone Number as well as the device IP address.

If it were possible, how would the VoIP service know which ATA device should recieve and incoming call?

Comment: As I said, only one at a time ATA adapter will be used, and devices have a different name. Let's assume first adapter starts making an outgoing call (the one who is first), if the second ATA tries to make a call at the same time, it will be rejected. The problem could be to receive incoming calls, since in this case, as you noted, Voip service don't know which device the call should be addressed to.

Comment: @triwo As I said you cannot register 2 SIP devices with the same phone number. The SIP Registration Server will reject the 2nd registration (unless your VoIP provider is incompetent). Note: I used to work as 2nd line tech support for a VoIP provider ...